# Stored Procedure SYNTAX error near 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, syntax-error

Does anyone know what is causing the error: "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'WHERE'"

```
CREATE PROC proc_ProductInf
    @SalesOrderID int,
    @SalesOrderOut int OUTPUT,
    @OrderDate datetime OUTPUT,
    @ShipDate int OUTPUT,
    @CityState varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @SalesOrderOut = @SalesOrderID

SET @OrderDate = (SELECT OrderDate FROM sALES.SalesOrderHeader )

SET @CityState = (
    SELECT          City, State
    FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
    ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
    WHERE           SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
    )

END

DECLARE @OrderNum int, @Date datetime, @Qty int
EXEC proc_ProductInf 63936, @SalesHeaderOut=@OrderNum OUTPUT,
    @OrderDate=@Date OUTPUT,
    @NumItems=@Qty OUTPUT
```

Comment: Please tag RDBMS. You should have seen [a pop up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/73226) already reminding you of this when asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying **ON** what to join Person.Address to Person.StateProvince.

```
SET @CityState = (
    SELECT          City, State
    FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
    ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
    ON              a.AddressStateProvinceID = st.StateProvinceID
    WHERE           SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
    )

END
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be an `on` clause.  More importantly, you cannot set two values at once.  So, concatenate them together:

```
SET @CityState = (
    SELECT          City + ', ' + State
    FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
    ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
    ON           SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
    );
```

Or,you can write it without the `set`:

```
    SELECT @CityState = City + ', ' + State
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s LEFT OUTER JOIN
         Person.Address a
         ON s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         Person.StateProvince st
         ON SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID;
```

It is also good practice to end each statement with a semicolon.

Comment: I ran it with ON SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID; but the semi-colon resulted in an error message. So, I did it without the semi-colon. Now the error message is invalid column name 'State' and ONLY one expression can be specified in the select list

Comment: @Eda . . . Only one expression *is* specified in the `select` list in both these queries, so that seems like a strange message.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to write like instead of having two table hits and you are fetching some random date instead this will be a better option!!

```
    SELECT        @CityState =  a.City+' '+a.State,@OrderDate = s.OrderDate
    FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader s     
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Address a
    ON              s.ShipToAddressID = a.AddressID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.StateProvince st
   ON              a.AddressStateProvinceID = st.StateProvinceID
    WHERE           SalesOrderID = @SalesOrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `ON` clause for a condition on the last `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Depending on which RDBMS you're using (I'm guessing it's Microsoft because of the @ variables), the `ON` clause may be required.